What metrics do I need to consider when changing rim size, and how can I find out what I have?
I have a 2017 ford edge sport. It came with the 21 inch tires which apart from being super expensive also don't give quite the same cushy ride that 18 inch tires with a similar diameter would. I'm finding lots of information on swapping tire sizes and have settled on a target size, 245/60 R18

What I'm not finding much info on is rim dimensions. I believe that rims have a width and an offset. Aside from breaking out the calipers, would that be stamped anywhere on the rim? I'm not looking to change the width of the front or rear axle at all, so I assume both of those measurements are important.
Finally, I assume that since I'd be getting 20mm less tire width, I might need to get a rim with higher offset if I wanted the exterior tire-to-tire width to be the same, but realistically if I matched the offset between old and new rim it'd only be 10mm on either side of the tire, right? So I'd lose 20 mm on the overall assembly, and the tires would be 20mm further apart (as opposed to the entire assembly being 40mm shorter). Can anyone confirm this?

If a rim is going to have the size stamped on it, it'd most likely be where the air pressure is at (I'd call it "inside" but don't really know if that's what it's called ... under where the tire is at when its installed).

Oh bummer, so not something I could look for on say the the backside of the face; I'd need to take it somewhere and have them break the bead.

Unfortunately, yes ... if it's stamped on the rim, that's where it would most likely be. You could check on the outer surface, but if it's not there, you'd only find it inside.

A trim level variation of your vehicle came with 18" wheels. Use those rims. Depending on how much you would want to spend maybe get used ones.
